# why android monkey has the permission to inject input events?

Tags: android, autotest, monkey

I know there is a permission check (pid/uid) when calling InputManager.

the UID of monkey process is not equal with the UID of current activity.
but why monkey process could inject event into the current window of activity?

Comment: nativeInjectInputEvent(event, injectorPid, injectorUid, syncMode, timeoutMillis);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because "adb shell" user have the permission. Check /etc/permissions/platform.xml:

```
<assign-permission name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" uid="shell" />
```

Answer (score 1):

monkey process start by adb shell, adbd process folk the monkey process. monkey process belong to root user group.

`adb shell monkey --port 12345`

USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME

root      1     0     676    520   c0159a9c 00010378 S /init

root      19691 1     4716   452   ffffffff 00018498 S /sbin/adbd

root      5972  19691 440824 19700 ffffffff 40077dc8 S com.android.commands.monkey

Comment: Yes, on an emulator or engineering build where ADB runs as root.  On a secured device, monkey will presumably probably run as ADB's shell user instead, which also has the permission for injection, as Google has wisely decreed that a consumer device should be usable for *ordinary* app development/testing.